# Remote domain: DNS record A exists when NS does not

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have encountered a domain for which I can sucessfully retrieve a DNS A record. At the same time, however, any public DNS server seems to return empty NS record. The domain in question is **bluedriving.com**.

I have looked up the domain with the [DNSViz tool](https://dnsviz.net/d/bluedriving.com/dnssec/) - but it gives confusing answer as well. How is this possible? Is this a valid DNS setup? I thought it should be impossible for A record to exist without a NS record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Non-standard *domain parking* DNS server

The `this-domain-for-sale.com` or `52.20.26.87` is a misconfigured authoritative name server, as it does not respond with the same NS records as the parent zone.

It seems like a BuyDomains.com's non-standard solution for *domain parking* that responds with `IN A 207.148.248.143` to just any domain...

- whether authoritative:

  ```
  $ dig bluedriving.com ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143

  $ dig scholarmarket.com ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143
  ns.buydomains.com. bd-operations.namemedia.com. 2016121022 86400 7200 604800 300

  $ dig collapsereport.com ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143
  ns.buydomains.com. bd-operations.namemedia.com. 2017060510 86400 7200 604800 300
  ```
- or not:

  ```
  $ dig buydomains.com ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143

  $ dig serverfault.com ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143

  $ dig icann.org ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143

  $ dig fbi.gov ANY @52.20.26.87 +short
  207.148.248.143
  ```

It also claims to be authoritative for most TLDs, including `com`, `net`, `org`, `gov` and many *country code top-level domain*s (ccTLD):

```
$ dig com NS @52.20.26.87 +noall +authority
com. 300 IN SOA ns.buydomains.com. hostmaster.buydomains.com. 115002911 86400 7200 604800 300
```

## Diagnostic steps

#### Understanding DNSViz

The DNSViz was designed for analyzing DNSSEC, and `bluedriving.com` is an unsigned domain. That is why it might *seem* confusing.

```
   Domain Name: BLUEDRIVING.COM
   . . .
   Name Server: NS.BUYDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: THIS-DOMAIN-FOR-SALE.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
```

DNSViz visualizes the status of any DNS zone and also lists configuration errors. Thus, it is able to tell what is going on:

> The following NS name(s) were found in the delegation NS RRset (i.e., in the com zone), but not in the authoritative NS RRset: `ns.buydomains.com`, `this-domain-for-sale.com`

As well as the other errors with the configuration:

> - `bluedriving.com` zone:
>
>   - The following NS name(s) did not resolve to address(es): `ns.buydomains.com`
>   - The server(s) were not responsive to queries over UDP. (`52.4.207.204`)
> - `bluedriving.com/A`:
>
>   - No response was received from the server over UDP (tried 12 times). (`52.4.207.204`, `UDP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_KN`)

#### Using `dig +trace`

If you run local diagnostics with `dig bluedriving.com +trace` you can see the same:

1. One of the `.com` name servers (`[a-m]{1}.gtld-servers.net`) responds with:

   ```
   bluedriving.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns.buydomains.com.
   bluedriving.com. 172800  IN  NS  this-domain-for-sale.com.
   ```
2. There is an error as one of the name servers does not exist:

   ```
   couldn't get address for 'ns.buydomains.com': not found
   ```
3. The other name server responds with an A record:

   ```
   bluedriving.com. 3600    IN  A   207.148.248.143
   ;; Received 60 bytes from 52.20.26.87#53(this-domain-for-sale.com) in 163 ms
   ```

It only works because it eventually gets an answer (`A`) from an authoritative name server (over TCP).

#### Deducing the likely implementation

The implementation behind this seems like a PowerDNS server that has TLD zones with a wildcard `A` record.

```
$ dig version.bind CHAOS TXT @52.20.26.87 +short
"PowerDNS Authoritative Server 3.4.7 (jenkins@autotest.powerdns.com built 20151103151158 root@autotest.powerdns.com)"
```

A PowerDNS server could have many different [backends](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/backends/), but despite the data source the records are equivalent to per TLD BIND zones having:

```
com.   3600  IN  SOA  ns.buydomains.com. hostmaster.buydomains.com. (
                      115002911 86400 7200 604800 300
                      )
*.com. 3600  IN  A    207.148.248.143
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent explanation. Thank you especially for the local dig queries to diagnose it. So it is incorrect DNS setup, but it works just barely enough to provide the A answers to any domain.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the SOA and other data on this domain has been restricted for privacy. [lookup.icann.org](https://lookup.icann.org/en/lookup) shows the nameservers as `ns.buydomains.com` and `this-domain-for-sale.com` which are clearly private nameservers; this may have something to do with the SOA being less than visible.

Comment: There is no such thing as restricting SOA for privacy; the WHOIS (owner / admin / tech) contact information for the domain is `REDACTED FOR PRIVACY`, but the SOA is not part of that, but a DNS concept.

Comment: The name server `this-domain-for-sale.com` claims it is authoritative for entire `.com`: `com. 300 IN SOA ns.buydomains.com. hostmaster.buydomains.com. 115002911 86400 7200 604800 300`. It is a misconfigured or a non-standard authoritative name server. The purpose of it as well as the technical details are explained in my answer.